# JavaScript separating string values

Tags: javascript, html

i want to separate this date/time "Tue, 21 Mar 2017 15:49:25 +0300". I want to be able to get "Tue","21","Mar","2017" in separate variable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: split them into array not variables

Comment: if you could help with demonstration, I am new to it.

Comment: how this part `15:49:25 +0300` should be treated? removed, ignored or remained as last chunk?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```js
var date = new Date("Tue, 21 Mar 2017 15:49:25 +0300");
    var day = date.getDay();
    var dom = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getYear();
    alert(day + " " + dom + " " + month + " " + parseInt(year+1900));
```

More details can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use split to get and array of variables, without using any extra libraries.

```js
a="Tue, 21 Mar 2017 15:49:25 +0300"
a=a.replace("," , "")
b=a.split(' ').slice(0,4)
const weekday    = b[0]
const dayofmonth = b[1]
const month      = b[2]
const year       = b[3]
console.log(weekday)
console.log(dayofmonth)
console.log(month)
console.log(year)
```

**Output**
Tue
21
Mar
2017

Answer (score 1):

- First replace the `comma`
- Split it using space
- Since you want only first 4 parts, use `slice`

Check the program

```js
var a="Tue, 21 Mar 2017 15:49:25 +0300";
a=a.replace(",","").split(" ");
a=a.slice(0,4);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Or you can `.split(/[ ,]+/)` and not bother with the `.replace()`.

Comment: Yes. But in a comment in question, OP said that he is a noob. So I think giving regex may be hard to him.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest using excellent moment.js library.

```
import moment from 'moment'

const date = "Tue, 21 Mar 2017 15:49:25 +0300"
const day = moment(date).format('DD')
const year = moment(date).format('YYYY')
const month = moment(date).format('MM')
const weekday = moment(date).format('ddd')
```

great docs https://momentjs.com/guides/

Comment: included.. for comprehensive documentation see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Answer (score 1):

```js
a = 'Tue, 21 Mar 2017 15:49:25 +0300';
splitArray = a.split(' ');

dayOfWeek = splitArray[0].replace(',', '');
dayOfMonth = splitArray[1];
month = splitArray[2];
year = splitArray[3];
time = splitArray[4];
timezoneShift = splitArray[5];

console.log(dayOfWeek);
console.log(dayOfMonth);
console.log(month);
console.log(year);
console.log(time);
console.log(timezoneShift);
```